# Normal map creation

Tags: mesh

I have prepared a hi poly version of a rocket and a lo poly version of it.
[image]
Both are at exactely the same position. They are 2 separate objects.

In all videos that I have seen, people select both models at the same time, then they click "BakeMode:"->"Normals", and that creates a normal map.

However, I can not select both meshes at the same time, and when I click "Bake", I am getting a "circular reference in texture stack" error.

I have uploaded my Blender file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38512

Would anybody be willing to take a look at my Blender file to see if I made an obvious errors?

Comment: i have an answer cooking, but before i post it i demand you tell me where you learned to texture like that.the texs on both the grenade and the launcher are amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "loop in texture stacks" tells me it's trying to bake to a texture of the texture it baking of, of the texture its baking to, of the texture.... ect. ect. All you have to do is uncheck these little boxes that define which textures are active on the mesh so that the texture your trying to bake to is the only active one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I also had to select "Selected to Active", and now it works. :-)

Comment: oh. i assumed you had that already. sorry! :/ just make sure you ahve your hipoly selected before your lowpoly